# Comparing a column's value with an array (or a series) of decreasing size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have the following dataframe. (This isn't necessarily a dataframe; a solution on the numpy array `df.values` would also be sufficient)

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)),columns=['a', 'b'])
df

        a           b
0   0.374540    0.950714
1   0.731994    0.598658
2   0.156019    0.155995
3   0.058084    0.866176
4   0.601115    0.708073
5   0.020584    0.969910
6   0.832443    0.212339
7   0.181825    0.183405
8   0.304242    0.524756
9   0.431945    0.291229
```

I want to include a new column that has the value as per the below logic:

*True : If any of the `b` values after a particular `a` value is greater than that partiulcar `a` value*
*False : Otherwise*

The expected output would be: 
(See the explanation for some of the rows below)

```
       a           b      c
0   0.374540    0.950714  True
1   0.731994    0.598658  True
2   0.156019    0.155995  True
3   0.058084    0.866176  True   <- np.any(0.058084 < np.array([0.708073, 0.969910, 0.212339, 0.183405, 0.524756, 0.291229]))
4   0.601115    0.708073  True   <- np.any(0.601115 < np.array([0.969910, 0.212339, 0.183405, 0.524756, 0.291229]))
5   0.020584    0.969910  True   <- np.any(0.020584 < np.array([0.212339, 0.183405, 0.524756, 0.291229]))
6   0.832443    0.212339  False  <- np.any(0.832443 < np.array([0.183405, 0.524756, 0.291229]))
7   0.181825    0.183405  True   <- np.any(0.181825 < np.array([0.524756, 0.291229]))
8   0.304242    0.524756  False  <- np.any(0.304242  < np.array([0.291229]))
9   0.431945    0.291229  UNDEFINED <- Ignore this
```

The above should be possible with a for loop but what is the pandas/numpy way to do that?

I was trying for an approach where I apply a lambda function to `a` but l couldn't find a way to get the index of the respective `a` value to do the `np.any` comparison as shown above. (I have later discovered that `apply` is just syntactic sugar for a for loop, though)

```
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: np.any(x < df['b'].values[<i>:])) # Where <i> is the respective index value of x; which I didn't know how to find
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick would be to go from bottom up on `b` and look for accumulated maximum values and compare those against the corresponding values in `a`.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
a = df.a.values
b = df.b.values
out = a[:-1] < np.maximum.accumulate(b[::-1])[::-1][1:]
```

Porting over to `pandas`, the counterpart would be `df.cummax` for `np.maximum.accumulate`.

Sample run -

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
          a         b
0  0.374540  0.950714
1  0.731994  0.598658
2  0.156019  0.155995
3  0.058084  0.866176
4  0.601115  0.708073
5  0.020584  0.969910
6  0.832443  0.212339
7  0.181825  0.183405
8  0.304242  0.524756
9  0.431945  0.291229

In [46]: out
Out[46]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer by @Divakar, the pandas approach using `cummax()` would be:

```
df['c'] = df['a'] < df['b'][::-1].cummax()[::-1].reset_index(drop=True).shift(-1)

print(df)  

        a         b      c
0  0.374540  0.950714   True
1  0.731994  0.598658   True
2  0.156019  0.155995   True
3  0.058084  0.866176   True
4  0.601115  0.708073   True
5  0.020584  0.969910   True
6  0.832443  0.212339  False
7  0.181825  0.183405   True
8  0.304242  0.524756  False
9  0.431945  0.291229  False
```

Comment: Might need a shift there : `df['a'].shift(1)`?

Comment: Thanks @Divakar! I missed it. Added `df['b'][::-1].cummax()[::-1].reset_index(drop=True).shift(-1)`. I think we can't shift `df['a']` here.